# Weird chrome errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, anonymous-function

I am developing my website which has got so many jquery functions and then I noticed something weird in chrome's web developer console. It causes a simple $('elem').slideDown(); function, but till now it worked fine .. and it is crazy, because I did not change that function.
The three errors I've getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined chrome-extension://nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn/jquery.min.js:14
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined chrome-extension://nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn/common.js:37
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined chrome-extension://nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn/content.js:125
```

When I open the error message, there is only this: (anonymous function). I have no idea whats wrong and by the way the script works.

What do you guys think?

Ps: Sorry for my english knowledge.

Comment: This may not be coming from your code, but from a bug in an extension to chrome. Can you remove all extensions and try again?

Comment: Is there anything noteworthy on those lines in the code (line 37 in your common.js file, etc)?

Comment: The id suggests that it might be this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docs-pdfpowerpoint-viewer/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn Disable it and try again?

Comment: The first answer won, in Incognito mode I dont getting these errors - thanks!
The common.js file isnt mine.

Comment: Voting to close as "too localized", since this has nothing to do with the OP's programming, but with one particular browser's configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to be the extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docs-pdfpowerpoint-viewer/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn?hl=en

Uninstall it and see if it magically starts to work.

Comment: Thank you! This extension caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from one of your chrome extensions (as it says in the error message).

Check your directory:

C:\Users[YOUR USER NAME HERE]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn

The 'nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn' part is from your error message, so once you change the path above to have your username, you should be able to find the plugin causing the issue.

Also, after reading the comments, I can confirm that it is the plugin found [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docs-pdfpowerpoint-viewer/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn?hl=en) that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing the same page in "incognito mode" `File > New Incognito Window`

Usually browser extensions are turned off, so this is easiest to test without actually having to disable or uninstall them all.